# About Winform threading in UI C#

Tags: c#, winforms

When I use a delegate method to run my method in order to let the UI refresh, the UI does not refresh.  I want stop the UI from freezing while the method runs, what can I do?

```
    private void SearchToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartMethod));
        t.Start();
    }
    private delegate void InvokeDelegate();
    public void StartMethod()
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(SearchData));
    }

    public void SearchData()
    {

        if (searchKeywordTextBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please type the keyword!");
        }
        else
        {
            if (searchDateTimePicker.Checked == true)
            {
                switch (selectRangeComboBox.Text)
                {
                    case "Day": showDataToresultDataGridViewOnDay(searchKeywordTextBox.Text);
                        break;
                    case "Month": showDataToresultDataGridViewInMonth(searchKeywordTextBox.Text);
                        break;
                    case "Year": showDataToresultDataGridViewInYear(searchKeywordTextBox.Text);
                        break;
                    default: MessageBox.Show("Please select a Section");
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                showDataToresultDataGridView(searchKeywordTextBox.Text);
            }

        }
    }
    public void showDataToresultDataGridViewOnDay(string keyword)
    {
        DataGridView dayGrid = resultDataGridView;
        ShowResultDay day = new ShowResultDay();
        resultDataGridView.DataSource = day.ShowGridDay(searchDateTimePicker.Value.Day, searchDateTimePicker.Value.Month, searchDateTimePicker.Value.Year, keyword);
        resultLabel.Text = "Showing " + resultDataGridView.RowCount + " records in " + searchDateTimePicker.Value.Day + "/" + searchDateTimePicker.Value.Month + "/" + searchDateTimePicker.Value.Year;
    }
    public void showDataToresultDataGridViewInMonth(string keyword)
    {
        DataGridView monthGrid = resultDataGridView;
        ShowResultMonth month = new ShowResultMonth();
        resultDataGridView.DataSource = month.ShowGridMonth(searchDateTimePicker.Value.Month, searchDateTimePicker.Value.Year, keyword);
        resultLabel.Text = "Showing " + resultDataGridView.RowCount + " records in " + searchDateTimePicker.Value.Month + "/" + searchDateTimePicker.Value.Year;
    }
    public void showDataToresultDataGridViewInYear(string keyword)
    {
        DataGridView yearGrid = resultDataGridView;
        ShowResultYear year = new ShowResultYear();
        resultDataGridView.DataSource = year.ShowGridYear(searchDateTimePicker.Value.Year, keyword);
        resultLabel.Text = "Showing " + resultDataGridView.RowCount + " records in " + searchDateTimePicker.Value.Year;
    }
    public void showDataToresultDataGridView(string keyword)
    {
        ShowAllData all = new ShowAllData();
        var results = all.ShowGirdAll(keyword);
        resultDataGridView.DataSource = results;
        resultLabel.Text = "Showing " + resultDataGridView.RowCount + " records";
    }
```

Comment: Do you understand how BeginInvoke works? It does you no good to have StartMethod called from a background thread if all it does is schedule SearchData to be invoked back on the UI thread. Even though you've created a background thread, it's pointless because you're still doing all the work on the UI thread. No matter how you slice it, you'll need to separate UI code from background code if you want them to run on different threads.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class, that has been implemented expressly to make multi-threading easier in WinForms.

Then I'd suggest another thing:
don't open the messageboxes from the the background thread, but check properties and fields before to start the thread, and then run only the search in the non-ui thread.

Example of background worker usage:

```
// Initialization
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);

// Start elaboration
bw.RunWorkerAsync(objectArgument);

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   // do your work (we are in the background-thread)
   // when you have finished, set your results in the e.Result property
   // N.B. don't show anything because we are in the background-thread
}

void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   // here we have finished the work (we are in the UI-thread)
   // result is set in e.Result property
   // N.B. check e.Error property before to get e.Result because
   //      if there's an error e.Result throws an exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Native Win32 API or MFC , Dot-net framework doesn't support multithreaded UI method's *calls for control's . Thus you can't create UI control (window) in any thread and call it's method and set property from another one !
(*here and below - UI method's that updates (refreshes) UI context . You can read data from control and can't write to) 
By the way , in the native environment such calls don't work reliably too, sometimes throwing badly managed exception ...
But managed environment can not allow the method call would cause an exception at all ! It just 'freezes' a such call and do nothing to refresh .
Incidentally, this feature of the platform is not only for background threads . Whether calling BeginInvoke (from the built-in thread pool), or creating a user's non-background thread by another way you'll get the same problem .
In your specific case I cannot see any reason to have two or more threads share the same control - it is also dangerous in terms of data safety . Typically, other threads (and generally parallelism) are used for entirely different purposes: for any long time computing , I/O operations of databases , files, network.
Although, of course, you can invoke some Message Boxes in other thread .